# store dynamically generate html code in php variable

Tags: php, file, output

I am trying to generate an PHP if statement dynamically. i.e. the user types in some stuff on a PHP page which then generates and output.php (all static). I cant use MySql or any other database applications.

I am making use of the heredoc's; escaping all the variables and tags PHP wants to interpret as code. The Problem is just for some reason I can't escape the closing tag ?> by putting a blackslash in front of it. Does anyone know how I can circumvent this problem?

This is what I have so far:

```
$fp = fopen('generated.php', 'w');

fwrite($fp,$header);
fwrite($fp,$options);
fwrite($fp,$body);

$ifstatment = "";
for($x=0;$x<count($myReasons); $x++)
{
   $ifstatment.= <<<EST
   \<?php
       if(\$myReasons['$x']== $x)
       {
         \$account = $myAccounts[$x];
       }
     \?>
EST;
}
fwrite($fp,$ifstatment);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Is there actually a space before the `EST;`?  You can't have that: https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: no there isn't, thats just the code intentation from stackoverflow